# Is there an optimal algorithm for visiting nodes in directed acyclic graph neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks, algorithms, conv-neural-network, dag

Perhaps someone here could either give me the answer to my question directly, or maybe tell me the right terms to use to search for the answer.

**Question:**
In a directed acyclic graph neural network the layers can be interweaved. Now, as in all DAGs, a node can be excited after all the inputs have already been computed.

Is there a particular algorithm that can discover the order of visiting the nodes optimally, so that no extra computating cycles are wasted?

**What I have thought so far:**
Intuitively, and if I would go about it directly, I would say a "breadth first" strategy should do the trick. But I am not sure if this is the best solution. Besides, in that case you would need to define the depth of a layer in a DAG, which I guess can also be a bit messy.

Some modern packages have implemented such an algorithm already, but their documentation does not necessarily explain the principles behind the algorithm very well.

This is  a question that relates to statistical learning so maybe there is somebody who can help.  I want to know for my reference.

Comment: Some key words are " toplogical order" and "shortest path", in combination with "directed acyclic graph".

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard problem in DAGs, and the solution is known as [Topological Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). This can actually be done via [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), rather than [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) as suggested in the question.

In the case of non-recurrent neural networks, I am no expert but I would imagine that this is essentially always known implicitly. I say this because from my understanding, the common training method known as [backpropagation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backpropagation) would proceed in reverse topological order.